# Highlight table row when a part of a word is in a table data output MYSQL in HTML CSS PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have a table where mysql outputs football team names.
I want when one of the outputs contains the word Vroomshoopse that table row will be all fonts bold. But how do i do this? tried alot what i found on internet but couldn't find the right answer.

I want when the output from the `$row["naam"];` containts Vroomshoopse (the full word is Vroomshoopse Boys D1, but i want it for more teams so only Vroomshoopse needs to work) it will be highlighted.

This is my code:

```
<table class="table_knvb_stand">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headerbalk">
            <th></th>
            <th class="groottable">Team</th>
            <th class="kleintable">Gespeeld</th>
            <th class="kleintable">Winst</th>
            <th class="kleintable">Gelijk</th>
            <th class="kleintable">Verloren</th>
            <th class="kleintable">DPV</th>
            <th class="kleintable">DPT</th>
            <th class="kleintable">Punten</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
    <?php
    $list = $stand["List"];
    foreach ($list as $row)
    {
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="nr">
                <?php echo $row["Positie"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="groottable">
                <?php echo $row["naam"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["Gespeeld"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["Gewonnen"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["Gelijk"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["Verloren"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["DoelpuntenVoor"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["DoelpuntenTegen"]; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="kleintable">
                <?php echo $row["Punten"]; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is how it now looks:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a simple css class:

```
.boldClass
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

You could obviously do more with that if you wished, then I would change each table cell as follows (two examples from your code):

```
<td class="nr<?php echo (stristr($row['naam'],"vroomshoopse") ? " boldClass" : "");?>">
    <?php echo $row["Positie"]; ?>
</td>
<td class="groottable<?php echo (stristr($row['naam'],"vroomshoopse") ? " boldClass" : "");?>">
    <?php echo $row["naam"]; ?>
</td>
```

Comment: It is almost working but now it only adds boldClass before Vroomshoopse Boys D1. So it is not reading the class that should happen

Comment: the rest would be like: <td class="kleintable<?php echo (stristr($row['naam'],"vroomshoopse") ? " boldClass" : "");?>">

Comment: Got it! it was case sensitive THANKS

Comment: Great news :) Can you mark it as accepted answer? I'm trying to get enough reputation to offer a bounty to have one of my own questions answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention jQuery or javascript I would add a class to the row if $row["naam"] contains Vroomshoopse.
I updated the relevant parts of your code below.  The important lines are the style block at the top and the stuff right after your foreach.

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr.highlight {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
<table class="table_knvb_stand">
    <thead>
        ...
    <tbody>
    <?php
    $list = $stand["List"];
    foreach ($list as $row)
    {
        $class = '';
        if(stristr($row["naam"], 'Vroomshoopse') !== false) {
            $class = " class='highlight'"; 
        }
        ?>
        <tr<?php echo $class;?>>
            ...
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit: changed to stristr and removed strtolower thanks to the comment from Think

Comment: You can use [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) to avoid the `strtolower`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just use jQuery as shown below.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("table tr:contains('Vroomshoopse')").css('font-weight','bold'); 
      // Another line as above(line 2) for another team //

    });
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/aedjvg8e/)

**Add class method**

This method involves referencing a CSS class in you CSS file. It doesn't add inline CSS, which is good.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("table tr:contains('Vroomshoopse')").addClass('your_class_name');

                // Another line as above for another team //

            });
```

Note: **Contains** is case sensitive.
Don't forget to add the line of code below to your header

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't get the output from the database. It is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aedjvg8e/5/.
But it is not working here: http://vvvroomshoopseboys.nl/d1-stand.html

Comment: @AlexanderFT make sure you called jQuery CDN in your header--t should be working.